# Multiple web applications into one portal

Tags: web-applications, web

I am not pretty sure if this the right place for this question, if it is not i will tank you to redirect me.

Ok, well i am a web developer (Java, jsp, jpa, etc) now i finish a project for a company wich is web based, and i will start another one in a few days, but i don want to tu have multiple access paths like this "http://app1" "http://app2", instead it would be nice to have just one entry point like this "http://companypage" and then once inside a menu with the different options according the user profile, like this app1 app2, so the user do not have to enter his username and password for every application.

Right now i am reading about LifeRay wich seems to be what i need, but it requires to change my application in order to develop it as a portlet and i am not sure about changing so much.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [CAS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/cas.html)? This would provide the entry point for authentication. Each application would still need to have a common menu bar with all the applications a user has access to.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you are looking for some [Single sign-on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) implementation to your web applications.

Comment: This is very similar to what i am looking for, but i was thinking in something that can "wrap" all my web application, something like a container that provide same look and feel, security, data accesses, etc. In order to present to the users the applications like a whole instead a bunch of url's. i read about "portals" and seem to be what i need, the only problems is that requires to change a lot in my web layer in order to deploy it like a porlet.